# Getting Precision and Recall using sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, cross-validation

Using the code below, I have the `Accuracy` . Now I am trying to

1) find the `precision` and `recall` for each fold (10 folds total)

2) get the `mean` for `precision`

3) get the  `mean` for `recall`

This could be similar to `print(scores)` and `print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))` below.

Any thoughts?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

iris = datasets.load_iris()
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=10)
print(scores)  #[ 1. 0.93333333   1.  1. 0.86666667  1.  0.93333333   1.  1.  1.]
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2)) # Accuracy: 0.97 (+/- 0.09)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit different, because cross_val_score can't calculate precision/recall for non-binary classification, so you need to use recision_score, recall_score and make cross-validation manually. Parameter average='micro' calculates global precision/recall.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score

iris = datasets.load_iris()
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)

X = iris.data
y = iris.target
precision_scores = []
recall_scores = []
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    y_pred = clf.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
    precision_scores.append(precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='micro'))
    recall_scores.append(recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='micro'))

print(precision_scores)
print("Recall: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (np.mean(precision_scores), np.std(precision_scores) * 2))
print(recall_scores)
print("Recall: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (np.mean(recall_scores), np.std(recall_scores) * 2))
```

Comment: my `precision`, `recall`, and `accuracy` scores are all the exact same `[1.0, 0.93333333333333335, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8666666666666667, 1.0, 0.93333333333333335, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
average: 0.97 (+/- 0.09)` but this should not be the case. Why is this? How can we fix?

Comment: I got the same results. I think this is due to the data: iris dataset is too small and simple, so you could try using a bigger dataset.

Comment: I tried this set of code on the actual data set (`np.array` of `2163, 8719`)  that I am using and I still receive the same answer for `precision`, `recall`, and `accuracy`

Comment: any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Comment: changing the setting to `average='macro'` changed the `precision` and `recall` score but I'm not sure if it is an appropriate setting

Comment: Ah, I understand now. "micro" setting calculates TP, TN, FP, FN globally, so if values are constant (you can calculate them manually). Macro calculates these values for each label separately, so you can try to use it.

Comment: I used it and it worked. I am trying to determine overfitting and underfitting using this data. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Usually, if quality on test is signifincantly lower than quality on train, you have overfitting.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, recall_score, precision_score, 
                            accuracy_score, f1_score,roc_auc_score
          
def binary_classification_performance(y_test, y_pred):
    tp, fp, fn, tn = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred).ravel()
    accuracy = round(accuracy_score(y_pred = y_pred, y_true = y_test),2)
    precision = round(precision_score(y_pred = y_pred, y_true = y_test),2)
    recall = round(recall_score(y_pred = y_pred, y_true = y_test),2)
    f1_score = round(2*precision*recall/(precision + recall),2)
    specificity = round(tn/(tn+fp),2)
    npv = round(tn/(tn+fn),2)
    auc_roc = round(roc_auc_score(y_score = y_pred, y_true = y_test),2)


    result = pd.DataFrame({'Accuracy' : [accuracy],
                         'Precision (or PPV)' : [precision],
                         'Recall (senitivity or TPR)' : [recall],
                         'f1 score' : [f1_score],
                         'AUC_ROC' : [auc_roc],
                         'Specificty (or TNR)': [specificity],
                         'NPV' : [npv],
                         'True Positive' : [tp],
                         'True Negative' : [tn],
                         'False Positive':[fp],
                         'False Negative':[fn]})
    return result


binary_classification_performance(y_test, y_pred)
```